# Why the loss of Variational Autoencoder in many implementations have opposite sign from paper?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I think I understand the paper of Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes. And I am reading some tensorflow codes implementing this paper. But I don't understand their loss function in those codes. Since lots of codes are written in same way, probably I am wrong.

The problem is like this. The following equation is from [AEVB paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf). 
[image]
The loss function is like this equation. This equation can be divided into two: Regularization term and Reconstruction term. Therefore, it becomes

```
Loss_function = Regularization_term + Reconstruction_term
```

However, lots of codes implement this Regularization term in a negative sign, like

```
Loss_function = -Regularization_term + Reconstruction_term
```

For example, in [this code](https://github.com/tegg89/VAE-Tensorflow/blob/master/model.py), 79th line shows Regularization term as

```
KLD = -.5 * tf.reduce_sum(1. + enc_logsd - tf.pow(enc_mu, 2) - tf.exp(enc_logsd), reduction_indices=1)
```

And then, it just adds to Reconstruction term.

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(KLD + BCE)
```

I don't understand. The sign of KLD is opposite from equation from the paper. There are lots of codes like this. I think I am wrong but I don't know what is wrong. Can you explain why it should be like this?

Reference codes: [code1](https://github.com/ikostrikov/TensorFlow-VAE-GAN-DRAW/blob/master/vae.py), [code2](https://github.com/hwalsuklee/tensorflow-mnist-VAE/blob/master/vae.py), [code3](https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-11-27/vae.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Equation (10) is the log-likelihood loss we want to maximize. It is equivalent to minimizing the negative log-likelihood (NLL). This is what optimization functions do in practice. Note that the `Reconstruction_term` is already negated in `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` (see https://github.com/tegg89/VAE-Tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L96). We need to negate the `Regularization_term` as well.

So the code implements `Loss_function = -Regularization_term + -Reconstruction_term`.

Comment: perfect, many thanks! had the same question indeed and was very confused about this.